# How to apply palette.secondary to button? MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am experimenting with MUI themes. Right now I have a nested case of 2 different themes on 2 MUI buttons.

I cannot seem to get the palette. secondary quality to apply no matter the method, sx prop, styles prop, color prop, or bgColor prop.

Here is a screenshot of my theme setup and the resultant output.

The button on the right is meant to be shown as the secondary color red but persists as the primary color green.

Any successful methods for applying the secondary theme palette would be much appreciated. Kind of hitting my head against a wall here.

[image]

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/button.js';
import { createTheme, useTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { red, green, purple } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { borderColor, palette } from '@mui/system';

const theme1 = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: purple[500],
    },
  },
});
const theme2 = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: green[500],
    },
    secondary: {
      main: red[500]
    }
  },
});


function App() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
        <Button/>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme2}>
          <Button color="secondary"/>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks,
Brandon

Comment: How does that `Button` component look like? It's not a MUI `<Button>`, right?

Comment: it's just one abstraction up so the props should carry down I believe. What this button component wraps is a mui button

Comment: There must be something breaking there along this path, because nesting themes with secondary colors doesn't have any problems with regular MUI `<Button>`s. You can check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/themenesting-material-demo-forked-6862l?file=/demo.js) for an example.